# Microsoft.Data.SQLite parameters not working

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I'm building a database kiosk using Microsoft.Data.SQLite. I'm using parameterized queries when building commands. This WAS working until VS was having build problems, and after applying various updates (detailed below), my parameters are no longer being applied. Hardcoding the values into the commandText works.

I was previously using the basic

```
selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Table", Table)
```

and I tried using a more explicit parameter. Here's the full command:

```
public static List<String> GetTables(string Table) // Get the Items in a Table
        {
            List<String> entries = new List<string>();

            using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection(ConnectionString)) // the db
            {
                db.Open();

                SqliteCommand selectCommand = new SqliteCommand("SELECT Item FROM @Table;", db);

                selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Table", SqliteType.Text).Value = Table;

                SqliteDataReader query = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (query.Read()) // while still reading data
                {
                    entries.Add(query.GetString(0)); // add string to entries
                }

                db.Close();
            }

            return entries;
        }
```

But the parameter still isn't being applied. Here's the full error:

```
SQLite Error 1: 'near "@Table": syntax error'.
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.<PrepareAndEnumerateStatements>d__62.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader()
at DataAccessLibrary.DataAccess.GetTables(String Table)
at brogle.SelectionPage.<LoadItemGridContent>d__8.MoveNext()}   Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException
```

Clearly, `@Table` isn't being changed to the string Table, whose value is "Bulbs". (There is a table "Bulbs", and again, hardcoding that into the command works as expected.) Debugging shows that the command accepts the parameter `@Table` with value "Bulbs".

To solve my build issues (code analysis was throwing errors) I installed Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers, updated SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_winsqlite3 and Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform to latest stable, and updated VS to 15.9.7.

If you need more details about anything, I can provide. Thanks.

Comment: You can't parameterise table names like that. You'll need to add it in using string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's for parameters. You can not give table names that way, what you can do for workaround is this :

```
SqliteCommand selectCommand = new SqliteCommand("SELECT Item FROM "+Table, db);
```

For more detail please refer [**Retrieve data from the SQLite database**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sqlite-databases#retrieve-data-from-the-sqlite-database) official document.